# draw line without default selection in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Good Night, dear colleages!
I need two draw application with two buttons: selection and draw line.
The button "selection" should select shapes to tranform them.
THe button draw line shoul draw line.

Now my code draw line and made it selected. I want to devide this functions. How should I solve my problem?

```js
var Line = (function() {
  function Line(canvas) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.isDrawing = false;
    this.bindEvents();
  }

  Line.prototype.bindEvents = function() {
    var inst = this;
    inst.canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o) {
      inst.onMouseDown(o);
    });
    inst.canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o) {
      inst.onMouseMove(o);
    });
    inst.canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o) {
      inst.onMouseUp(o);
    });
    inst.canvas.on('object:moving', function(o) {
      inst.disable();
    })
  }

  Line.prototype.onMouseUp = function(o) {
    var inst = this;
    if (inst.isEnable()) {
      inst.disable();
    }
  };

  Line.prototype.onMouseMove = function(o) {
    var inst = this;
    if (!inst.isEnable()) {
      return;
    }

    var pointer = inst.canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    var activeObj = inst.canvas.getActiveObject();

    activeObj.set({
      x2: pointer.x,
      y2: pointer.y
    });
    activeObj.setCoords();
    inst.canvas.renderAll();
  };

  Line.prototype.onMouseDown = function(o) {
    var inst = this;
    inst.enable();

    var pointer = inst.canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    origX = pointer.x;
    origY = pointer.y;

    var points = [pointer.x, pointer.y, pointer.x, pointer.y];
    var line = new fabric.Line(points, {
      strokeWidth: 5,
      stroke: 'red',
      fill: 'red',
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
      hasBorders: false,
      hasControls: false
    });
    inst.canvas.add(line).setActiveObject(line);
  };

  Line.prototype.isEnable = function() {
    return this.isDrawing;
  }

  Line.prototype.enable = function() {
    this.isDrawing = true;
  }

  Line.prototype.disable = function() {
    this.isDrawing = false;
  }

  return Line;
}());
console.log(fabric);
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var line = new Line(canvas);
```

```html
<div id="canvasContainer">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="border: solid 1px"></canvas>
</div>
  <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.4.0/fabric.min.js"
  ></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you have both drawing and selecting because Fabric makes it's associated canvas selectable by default.

This behaviour is controlled by changing the boolean **.selection** property on the object returned by calling `new fabric.Canvas()`.

So all you have to do is set up two buttons (Select/Draw), set `canvas.selection` to the desired state and return from the mouseMove handler before doing any drawing in case `selection==true`.

Here's an example:

```js
function select(state) {
  canvas.selection = state;
}

var Line = (function() {
  function Line(canvas) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.isDrawing = false;
    this.bindEvents();
  }

  Line.prototype.bindEvents = function() {
    var inst = this;
    inst.canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o) {
      inst.onMouseDown(o);
    });
    inst.canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o) {
      inst.onMouseMove(o);
    });
    inst.canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o) {
      inst.onMouseUp(o);
    });
    inst.canvas.on('object:moving', function(o) {
      inst.disable();
    })
  }

  Line.prototype.onMouseUp = function(o) {
    var inst = this;
    if (inst.isEnable()) {
      inst.disable();
    }
  };

  Line.prototype.onMouseMove = function(o) {
    var inst = this;
    if (!inst.isEnable() || canvas.selection) {
      return;
    }

    var pointer = inst.canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    var activeObj = inst.canvas.getActiveObject();

    activeObj.set({
      x2: pointer.x,
      y2: pointer.y
    });
    activeObj.setCoords();
    inst.canvas.renderAll();
  };

  Line.prototype.onMouseDown = function(o) {
    var inst = this;
    inst.enable();

    var pointer = inst.canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    origX = pointer.x;
    origY = pointer.y;

    var points = [pointer.x, pointer.y, pointer.x, pointer.y];
    var line = new fabric.Line(points, {
      strokeWidth: 5,
      stroke: 'red',
      fill: 'red',
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
      hasBorders: false,
      hasControls: false
    });
    inst.canvas.add(line).setActiveObject(line);
  };

  Line.prototype.isEnable = function() {
    return this.isDrawing;
  }

  Line.prototype.enable = function() {
    this.isDrawing = true;
  }

  Line.prototype.disable = function() {
    this.isDrawing = false;
  }

  return Line;
}());
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.selection = false;
var line = new Line(canvas);
```

```html
<div id="canvasContainer">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="border: solid 1px"></canvas>
</div>
<button onclick='select(true);'>Select</button>
<button onclick='select(false);'>Draw</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
```